# How can I add an Author filter to the Media Library?

Tags: filters, author, media-library

By default the WordPress Media Library allows you to filter results by their type or date. How can I add a third drop down to list and filter by author?

Currently we have this:

[image]

I'd like to have the following:

[image]

According to [this ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16044) (unless I'm reading it wrong) the code was added three years ago to `/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-media-list-table.php` to allow this, but I don't see how this actually works.

[The codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/ajax_query_attachments_args) also says that it's possible to modify the media library modal window you get when editing a page or post with:

```
add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', 'show_current_user_attachments', 10, 1 );
function show_current_user_attachments( $query = array() ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if( $user_id ) {
        $query['author'] = $user_id;
    }
    return $query;
}
```

So I'd think that it's possible to do something similar on the main Media Library page, but I can't see how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your question you showed the image which is grid-view and that codex belongs to list-view. So I am confused here for which section you are talking about.

**Grid View :** not possible unless you change the core as they don't provide any hook and the whole media section was created by jquery, backbone and unserscore. Please look into media-grid.min.js or media-grid.js for code.

**List View :** in this view you can easily add dropdown. here is the script to do this. If you want then add `parse_query` or `pre_get_posts` filter to change the query for the dropdown. As I am setting `author` to url, wordpress itself sets it for me so need for those filters.

```
function media_add_author_dropdown()
{
    $scr = get_current_screen();
    if ( $scr->base !== 'upload' ) return;

    $author   = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'author', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $selected = (int)$author > 0 ? $author : '-1';
    $args = array(
        'show_option_none'   => 'All Authors',
        'name'               => 'author',
        'selected'           => $selected
    );
    wp_dropdown_users( $args );
}
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'media_add_author_dropdown');
```

Here are the references

1. [restrict_manage_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/restrict_manage_posts/)
2. [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)
3. [parse_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/parse_query)

**Edit #1: Added author filter after this [comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204779/how-can-i-add-an-author-filter-to-the-media-library/204857?noredirect=1#comment320285_204857)**

```
function author_filter($query) {
    if ( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if (isset($_GET['author']) && $_GET['author'] == -1) {
            $query->set('author', '');
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','author_filter');
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm after. I wasn't aware that there was a difference in filtering when changing views in the library. I'll need to look through this a little more, and possibly combine it with the code I mentioned regarding the modal part. Thanks.

Comment: I just noticed, and I'm not sure if this is due to something in the latest version of WP, or if I just never saw it when it was first posted, however now filters don't work properly when 'All Authors' is selected. For example, If I filter by images, all dates, and all authors, nothing is returned. Also, searching by text fails when 'All Authors' is chosen.

Comment: @j08691 please check updated code as per requirement hope its works now.

Comment: @Webloper any idea why when i click the author name as explained below, nothing is found even though that author uploaded media? i wanted to add the dropdown but i don't think it will make a difference if the query parameter doesn't work. it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

If you need this for your own site then instead of code you can go to list view and click on author name under **Author** column. That would give you the list of media for that particular author. See below screenshot.

[image]

But if you are doing this for any client then you will need a code to provide user friendly way :) like the dropdown you shown in your screenshot :)

Comment: Sorry but that's not what I'm looking for.